# How to debug the error 'sh: 1: python3: not found' in running Python script in PHP

Tags: php, python, xampp

I want to run my Python script using PHP's shell_exec() and xammp on Mac. When I run it on terminal it is working, but when I run it on browser it shows this error 'sh: 1: python3: not found'

**PHP**

```php
$command = escapeshellcmd("python3 scrape.py");
$command_output = shell_exec($command." 2>&1");

echo $command_output;
```

**Python**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cgi,cgitb
import urllib.request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
from datetime import datetime
import re
import json

print ("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8\n")

print("hello")
```

Comment: You're trying to invoke `python3` from php without giving it a path (you're not invoking `scrape.py`, you're passing it as a file argument to `python3`).  You can either add its directory to your path, or invoke it with an absolute path.

Comment: I edited the code to this escapeshellcmd("/usr/local/bin/python3 scrape.py") and it shows this output 'sh: 1: /usr/local/bin/python3: not found'

Comment: Try `ls -l /usr/local/bin/python3` from your shell, verify that it exists and is executable.

Comment: it returns this: lrwxr-xr-x  1 amplabinc.  wheel  69 Apr  8 15:46 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3

Comment: Well, a symlink exists for it.  Try doing `ls -lL /usr/local/bin/python3` to make sure it resolved (i.e. add `L`).

Comment: @TomKarzes it shows this: -rwxrwxr-x  2 root  admin  9604 Mar 26 04:52 /usr/local/bin/python3

Comment: Well it looks like it's there and it's executable, so I'm not sure what's going on.  You can try running it directly by typing `/usr/local/bin/python3` from your shell, but I expect it will work.

Comment: Yes it is working in terminal. But still not in browser. Thanks for the help

Comment: it's working on shared hosting. but in xampp it's not